# How to "stick" two faces of two objects?

Tags: modeling, workflow

I'm totally lost and you are my last hope. I spent my day trying to stick these two faces with the magnet. I followed all the tutorials I found about to snap an object to the face of another object. I missed something but what?. Here the two faces.
Thanks.[image]

---

I forgot the other face I want to snap, sorry [image]

Comment: you want them to stick at the center?(at the yellow dot?)

Comment: Yes stick them at the center on the plan formed by the face shown on the image and try to rotating them on the same axe (x)

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the snap option (little red magnet icon) in order to do so. Right now you have it disabled. Then you need to choose the Snap Element you desire, in this case Face or Point.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly join the 2 meshes. Then select only the faces you want to stick (, in the image that you post the axis you want to scale is x so) press s to scale then press 0 (be sure you set pivot point to median before doing this).And the faces will stick together .
I am not sure however if thats the answer you are asking for.